# About elasticsearch group by two fields and then filter or order

Tags: elasticsearch

There is a `shareholder` index want to get below info

1. which holder invest the same company the most times

   select hld_id, com_id, count(*) from shareholder group by hld_id, com_id order by count(*) desc;
2. which holder invest company just two times, maybe duplicate records

   select hld_id, com_id from shareholder group by hld_id, com_id having count(*) = 2;

So how to implement above requirements by `elasticsearch` search query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the sample mapping, documents and aggregation query. I've figured three possible ways this can be done/achieved.

### Mapping:

```
PUT shareholder
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "hld_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "com_id":{
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Documents:

```
POST shareholder/_doc/1
{
  "hld_id": "001",
  "com_id": "001"
}

POST shareholder/_doc/2
{
  "hld_id": "001",
  "com_id": "002"
}

POST shareholder/_doc/3
{
  "hld_id": "002",
  "com_id": "001"
}

POST shareholder/_doc/4
{
  "hld_id": "002",
  "com_id": "002"
}

POST shareholder/_doc/5
{
  "hld_id": "002",
  "com_id": "002"               <--- Note I've changed this 
}
```

### Solution 1: Using Elasticsearch's aggregation

**Aggregation Query: 1**

Note that I've just made use of [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) pipelined firstly with `hld_id` and then with `com_id`

```
POST shareholder/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "share_hoder": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "hld_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "com_aggs": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "com_id",
            "order": {
              "_count": "desc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is how the response appear:

**Response:**

```
 {
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "share_hoder" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "002",
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "com_aggs" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "002",
                "doc_count" : 2                    <---- Count you are looking for
              },
              {
                "key" : "001",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "001",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "com_aggs" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "001",
                "doc_count" : 1
              },
              {
                "key" : "002",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Of course you may not get the representation of the result exactly as you are looking for because of the way Elasticsearch's aggregation works.

**Aggregation Query: 2**

For this, most of it is same as aggregation_1, where I've used two [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) but I've additionally made use of [Cardinality Aggregation Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) to get the count of hld_id and then I used further [Bucket Selector Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) in which I've added the conditions for `count()==2`

```
POST shareholder/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "share_holder": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "hld_id",
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "com_aggs": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "com_id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "count_filter":{
              "bucket_selector": {
                "buckets_path": {
                  "count_path": "_count"
                },
                "script": "params.count_path == 2"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is how the response appears.

**Response:**

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "share_holder" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "002",
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "com_aggs" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "002",                   
                "doc_count" : 2                     <---- Count == 2
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "001",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "com_aggs" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [ ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the second bucket is empty. I'm trying to see if I can filter the above query so that `"key": "001"` doesn't appear in first place.

### Solution 2: Using Elasticsearch SQL:

If you have the x-pack version of Kibana, you can probably execute the below queries in SQLish style:

**Query:1**

```
POST /_sql?format=txt
{
    "query": "SELECT hld_id, com_id, count(*) FROM shareholder GROUP BY hld_id, com_id ORDER BY count(*) desc"
}
```

**Response:**

```
    hld_id     |    com_id     |   count(*)    
---------------+---------------+---------------
002            |002            |2              
001            |001            |1              
001            |002            |1              
002            |001            |1
```

**Query 2:**

```
POST /_sql?format=txt
{
    "query": "SELECT hld_id, com_id FROM shareholder GROUP BY hld_id, com_id HAVING count(*) = 2"
}
```

**Response:**

```
    hld_id     |    com_id     
---------------+---------------
002            |002
```

### Solution 3: Using Script in Terms Aggregation

**Aggregation Query:**

```
POST shareholder/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "query_groupby_count": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
              doc['hld_id'].value + ", " + doc['com_id'].value
            """
        }
      }
    },
    "query_groupby_count_equals_2": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": """
              doc['hld_id'].value + ", " + doc['com_id'].value
            """
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "myaggs": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "count": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.count == 2"
          }

        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "query_groupby_count_equals_2" : {               <---- Group By Query For Count == 2
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "002, 002",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    },
    "query_groupby_count" : {                        <---- Group By Query
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "002, 002",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "001, 001",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "001, 002",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "002, 001",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Using CURL:**

First let us save the query in a `.txt` or `.json` file.

For e.g I created a file called `query.json`, copy and pasted only the query in that file.

```
{
    "query": "SELECT hld_id, com_id, count(*) FROM shareholder GROUP BY hld_id, com_id ORDER BY count(*) desc"
}
```

Now execute the below curl command where you'd refer the file as shown below:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_sql?format=txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @query.json
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!  but the answer cannot resolve my question. Query 1: ` select hld_id, com_id, count(*) from shareholder order by hld_id desc `

Comment: And query 2: `select hld_id, com_id, count(*) from shareholder group by hld_id order by hld_id having count(*) = 2`

Comment: @zhuguowei I've updated the answer, please do check.

Comment: I took some time to send the right request using curl, the trouble is how to escape the quotes. This is the example that could work  `"query": "SELECT hldId, comId, count(*) FROM shareholder where type = '\''Natural Person'\'' and hldId is not null GROUP BY hldId, comId order by count(*) desc limit 10"`

Comment: @zhuguowei I've added one more technique for your query in section `Solution 3` and I've mentioned another section `Using CURL` in my updated answer which is basically what you are looking for. Hope that should help you!!

Comment: Thanks very help Actually execute the sql in production failed(mean took too long time and no return so have to cancel task explicitly) because the big amount of data but the solution3 works and only took 158 seconds

Comment: could precisely filter count equals 2? now my workaround is specify a large size e.g. 1000 then combine bucket_selector in Solution 1

Comment: @zhuguowei Sorry, I've just updated my answer in Solution 3. Please check.